# Время исполнения flash баннера

Tags: flash, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли как-нибудь узнать сколько по времени выполняется один цикл анимации во флэш баннере? ( т.е. до того момента как его анимация начнет проигрываться снова ).
Ответ, пожалуйста, обоснуйте.

Ограничения: без копания в исходниках флэша; желательно узнать время в браузере ( js/php etc ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. И обосновывать тут нечего. Как вы с помощью javascript залезете в виртуальную машину Flash? Только если вы сами не открыли мост через `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Получается, что сайты, на которых в определённой областях размещен flash-баннер, просто проигрывают его некоторое время ( не равное времени анимационного цикла ), а потом подгружают новый, проигрывают его некоторое время и т.д., тем самым не заморачиваяются над тем, что баннер может несколько раз воспроизвестись?

Comment: Приведите пример сайта?